# How to check number of connections

Tags: tcp, limit, cpanel

My server have high loads.

CPU usage is low. Memory usage is low. IO is low.

So I improve maximum number of connections in cpanel.

Things are working.

However, where can I see detail? How do I know number of connections?

Any command in linux?

Comment: By number of connections, do you mean tcp connections as discussed [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67171/47538)?

Comment: something like what's stated in cpanel whm settings

Comment: oh ok. I was not aware of cpanel. But, I do see `whm` listens on ports 2086 and 2087. So, do you want to monitor the total connections in these ports alone?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/13254/number-of-connections-to-domains-on-a-cpanel-server) option addressing your problem?

Comment: cpanel also listens on 2082 and 2083 ports. @Jim Thio, are you talking about connections to cPanel or all the tcp connections to your server?

Comment: I think I want to know the bottle neck of my server. So I want to know total number of connections.

Comment: I think most connects to port 80